# How to do the git bisect for one repository and go to old version where latest version is causing trouble?

Tags: linux, git, svn, version-control, github

I have to go back to old version, where latest version is not working. So far i tried following but confusing because i see still all codes are same as latest:

```
git bisect start
git bisect bad
git biesct good <VERSION OR PACKAGENAME.VERSION.OF.OLD.NUMBER.WHICH.I.THINK.WAS.GOOD>

# NOW CONFUSING.. WHAT I HAVE TO TELL TO JUST USE THAT OLD VERSION? ONLY THE CHECKOUT COMMIT ID?
git checkout <old version commit id>?
```

How exactly you do that?

**Follow up:**

> Advertiser$ Hey we got a latest version up in the master 0 bugs.  (he
>   lied there is 100s of bugs, he just need us to test)

Step 1: curious@tester

```
tester$ cd /var/tmp
tester$ git clone git://site.com/pizzapasta.git
tester$ ./autogen.sh; make;make install; run;
tester$ # failed 40 bugs found, impossible to use it
```

Step 2: going back to old

```
tester$ cd /var/tmp/pizzapasta
tester$ git bisect start          # initialize
tester$ git bisect bad            # i marked my master/latest is BAD, i dont like/trust it
                                  # Now i am going to old version
tester$ git bisect good <COMMIT-U-THINK_GOOD> 
tester$ git checkout <COMMIT-ID-THAT-WAS-SHOWN-BY-GOOD>
tester$ ./autogen.sh; make; make install; run;
```

Running..... so the old is gold and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that the output of `git status` is empty - if your work is uncommitted, that might explain why you are seeing the same code again.

To go through the commands you've quoted, the first two are fine:

```
git bisect start
git bisect good
```

... which just say to start the bisection, and that the current version is bad.  Then, once you do:

```
git bisect bad <COMMIT-YOU-THINK-IS-GOOD>`
```

... git will *automatically move you* to a commit that is roughly half way between the commits you've marked as good and bad.  (A substantial part of the code might indeed be the same when you're at this new point in the history.)

(Note that doing `git bisect bad <COMMIT-YOU-THINK-IS-GOOD>` at that point is equivalent to doing `git checkout <COMMIT-YOU-THINK-IS-GOOD>` and `git bisect bad`.)

All you have to do at this point is *test the code*.  If the problem is still there, just do:

```
git bisect bad
```

... or if the version git has chosen seems to be good, just do:

```
git bisect good
```

In either of those cases, git will again automatically move you to a new version to test immediately when you enter those commands.  (If it moves you to a version that doesn't compile, or something similar, you can tell git to pick another one without marking the current version as good or bad by doing `git bisect skip`.)

Basically, you keep testing the new versions that git moves you to, until it outputs a message saying `f414f31 is the first bad commit` (or something similar).

Finally, to end the bisection and move yourself back to the branch / commit you were at before you started, just do:

```
git bisect reset
```

(You can also use that to abort the bisection at any point in the above if anything goes wrong, or you get confused.)

Comment: git bisect start; git bisect bad; git bisect good <COMMIT-U-THINK-IS-GOOD> ? my current master is bad i wanted to flag that as first and go to GOOD and test that one. Am i right.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, yes, those are sensible first steps in using `git bisect` successfully - the point is that after those steps you have to carry on testing the versions that git then selects (and automatically moves you to) until it can locate the first bad commit.

Comment: thank you, i just edited also my follow up its very excellent version controller. :)